# Что такое def?

Tags: joomla, php

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, что означает этот код?

```
$params->def( 'menutype', 'mainmenu' );
```

Переменной $params присваивается?

Answer (score 2):

Этот код означает, что у объекта содержащегося в переменной `$params` вызвали метод `def` с двумя параметрами `'menutype', 'mainmenu'`. Без исходников невозможно понять как изменяются переменные внутри объекта/класса.

Comment: У объекта, содержащегося в переменной $params (извините, совсем недавно начал копаться во всем этом) может у переменной, содержащейся в объекте?   Что-то  вашу запись я понять не могу. Как так? У объекта в переменной?

Comment: В переменной $params находится ссылка на объект, у которого и вызывается метод def.

Comment: Теперь понял. Благодарю.

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста нажмите на галочку под "пальцем вниз", чтобы ответить мой ответ как правильный

Comment: @GLAGOLA это джумла) Метод def - присвоение свойства, после этого $params['menutype'] после кучи проверок будет 'mainmenu'. Так, просто уточнил.

Answer (score 0):

В Joomla этот код значит: если в параметрах (компонента/модуля) задано значение переменной с идентификатором `'menutype'`, то вернется значение этой переменной. Если же оно не указано, то вернется `'mainmenu'` (значение по умолчанию).
Т.е. `$params->def` аналогичен `$params->get`. С той лишь разницей, что `get` возвращает либо значение переменной, либо `NULL`. А `def` возвращает либо значение переменной, либо значение по-умолчанию